# Superimpose labeling onto RGB image

Tags: image, matlab

I have two matrices where one is RxCx3 (RGB image) and the other is RxC (labelings). Most of the labels are zero and I would like to paint the non-zero labels on the RGB image. More specifically, I would like to superimpose the figure:

```
imagesc(labels)
```

onto the figure:

```
imshow(rgb)
```

except the zero values in labels. What is the quickest way to achieve it?

Comment: You can easily perform actions on non-zero labels with the handy indexing: find(Labels) will get you all the nonzero indices, use those to do what you want. I'm a little unclear about what you mean "paint the non-zero labels on the RGB image"

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1AK7N/ This also may help if I'm understanding you properly?

Comment: Well, why not post this as an answer, Akshaya?

Comment: @ypnos haha sure, I'll go ahead and put up a little writeup, but I don't really have the time to format/put real code snippets, so I'd appreciate some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here's my interpretation of your problem: You want to superimpose non-zero elements of a matrix onto an image (an example of this might be a heat map).

This page here will give you everything you need regarding the non-zero aspect, but generally you will do something like

```
find(Labels)
```

inside a processing section that will then only process those elements of "Labels" > 0. (You can make the expression inside "find" way more complex if your needs change)

[Find - Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html)

To actually superimpose the image though (you require labels), you need to make a decision. Physically alter the image to be displayed to show the labels or overlay the labels transparently. The following page has great information on achieving this result:

[Overlaying Image in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1AK7N/)

I suspect for your requirements, you'd want to take the transparency route (I would recommend it as well)